# Live HTTP for CURL

Tags: http, curl, live

I have series of curl commands that I want to translate into straight up HTTP requests.

I would like to use some live http utility that would record http requests made while I make the curl commands.  And from this, I will translate the curl commands to their corresponding http requests.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) - it is a great network analyzer and you can do so much more than just HTTP.

cURL also has some logging / debug functionality which may help.  See [CURLOPT_VERBOSE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTVERBOSE).